# Use strong mathematical induction to prove that $a_n \le 2^n$ for each integer $n\ge 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction

Let $a_0, a_1, a_2, .... $be the sequence defined recursively as

$a_0 = 1, a_1 = 2, a_k = a_{k-1} + a_{k-2}$ for each integer $k >=2$

I'm not sure how to work with sequences.

Comment: Do you mean $a_k=a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}$?  As in, the usual Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Do you know how induction works?

Comment: I did mean that. Edited. And yes, I think so. My Induction hypothesis should be that $n>1$ and that $a_k≥k$ for all integers $k$ such that $0≤k<n$

Comment: The induction hypothesis should be $a_k\leq 2^k$ for $0\leq k<n$, since that's what you're trying to prove.